# (NextJS / ReactJS) "Warning: Text content did not match. Server: ' ' Client: 'X'" Results in Odd Behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

**Context**

I've just started using Next.JS and have had no issues with it so far. However, while making this project to try and get more familiar with Next.JS, I have encountered this warning (see below) within the console:

[image: Warning within console]

Moreover, I believe this to be the culprit to unexpected behaviour when rendering my "board", or rather, a group of buttons.

[image: Picture of board / group of buttons with repeating X's]

It very well may be that I am missing something within my code (since I am relatively new to both ReactJS and NextJS, but I don't believe this is the case due to how in an earlier version of this project, the cells (buttons) that were being rendered did not match up with the 2D array that I used to represent these cells.

**Board.tsx**

```
// Components
import BoardProps from "../interfaces/boardProps";
import { useState } from "react";
import Cell from "./cell";

// Constants and Globals
const emptyCell = ' ';
const mineCell = 'X';

export default function Board({ numberOfCells }: BoardProps) {
    const [cells, setCells] = useState(createBoard(numberOfCells));
    const numberOfCellsInRowAndColumn = Math.sqrt(numberOfCells); // TODO: validate
    const renderableBoard = getRenderableBoard(cells, numberOfCellsInRowAndColumn);

    return (
        <div>
            {renderableBoard}
        </div>
    );
}

function createBoard(numberOfCells: number) {
    let board = Array(numberOfCells).fill(emptyCell);
    board = generateMines(board);

    return board;
}

function getRenderableBoard(cells: any[], numberOfCellsInRowAndColumn: number) {
    let renderableBoard = [];

    for (let row = 0; row < numberOfCellsInRowAndColumn; row++) {
        let renderableRow = [];

        for (let column = 0; column < numberOfCellsInRowAndColumn; column++) {
            renderableRow.push(<Cell key={column} value={cells[column]}/>);
        }

        renderableBoard.push(<div key={row}>{renderableRow}</div>);
    }

    return renderableBoard;
}

function generateMines(cells: any[]) {
    const percentageOfMines = 0.15;
    const numberOfCells = cells.length;
    const numberOfMines = Math.floor(numberOfCells * percentageOfMines);
    let copyOfCells = cells.slice();
    
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfMines; index++) {
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfMines);

        // Generates a random index until there are no duplicates
        while (copyOfCells[randomIndex] === mineCell) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfCells);
        }

        copyOfCells[randomIndex] = mineCell;
    }

    return copyOfCells;
}
```

**Cell.tsx**

```
// Components
import CellProps from "../interfaces/cellProps";

export default function Cell({ value }: CellProps) {
    return (
        <button>
            {value}
        </button>
    );
}
```

If anyone could tell me why I am receiving this error, or any insight at all, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Next.js your React code will run twice: on the server when pre-rendering the page and on the client during hydration. The issue happens because the `generateMines` function has a random factor to it which means you'll get 2 different version when it runs on the server and on the client. Try moving the logic to the client-side only.

Comment: Huge thanks @juliomalves. I'm new to next.js(and React in general) and this was killing me on a VERY simple project. There was no fetching of any kind so I didn't understand why the client would load any different than the server. I was loading a dataset through raw JSON and graphing a random selection. It was the random values the entire time. I didn't realize the client and server were generating different random values but that makes sense.